# rvm requirements with Xcode 4.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, rvm

Today I'm working in a Mac (I'm a Ubuntu user), and have some problems to install and configure the Ruby on Rails.

First I install the **homebrew**, and then **rvm**.

Then I was trying install the *rvm requirements* and get this error:

```
user:~ analistas$ rvm requirements
Checking requirements for osx.
Error: No available formula for gcc46 
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system........
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/analistas/.rvm/log/1395783259/update_system.log
+ printf %b '
Xcode version older than 4.6.2 installed, download and install newer version from:

    http://connect.apple.com

After installation open Xcode, go to Downloads and install Command Line Tools.
\n'

Xcode version older than 4.6.2 installed, download and install newer version from:

    http://connect.apple.com

After installation open Xcode, go to Downloads and install Command Line Tools.

+ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
user:~ analistas$
```

It's possible run `rvm requirements` with a older Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You can do `brew search rvm` and if you see and older version (I'm not sure which one supports older gcc). You can then do `brew install {whatever search returns}`